# Как написать аналог JQuery-кода на чистом JS onclick?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Всем доброго времени суток, пожалуйста, помогите написать на чистом js аналог:

```
$('div#but input').click(function() {                                           
    $('.textbox').val($('.textbox').val() + this.value.toString());
})
```

html:

```
    <input class="textbox" type="text" size="30" value="">
    <div id="but">
            <input type="submit" id="button" value="1">
            <input type="submit" id="button" value="2">
            <input type="submit" id="button" value="3">         
            <input type="submit" id="button" value="4">
            <input type="submit" id="button" value="5">
            <input type="submit" id="button" value="6">
            <input type="submit" id="button" value="7">
            <input type="submit" id="button" value="8">
            <input type="submit" id="button" value="9">
            <input type="submit" id="button" value="0">
            <input type="submit" id="button" value=".">
    </div>
```

Код ориентирован на последние версии хрома, только хрома.

Comment: @Mnwa, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

[Проверяем тут](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/eggq60df/1/)

```
var d = document,
    inp = d.querySelector('div#but input');
inp.addEventListener('click', function(){
    var txtBox = d.querySelectorAll('.textbox');
    for(var i = 0; i < txtBox.length; i++){
        txtBox[i].value += this.value.toString();
    }
}, false);
```

P.S. Если у вас несколько элементов input в элементе с id = but, то так:

```
var d = document,
    inp = d.querySelectorAll('div#but input');

function concatVal(){
    var txtBox = d.querySelectorAll('.textbox');
    for(var i = 0; i < txtBox.length; i++){
        txtBox[i].value += this.value.toString();
    }
}
for(var i = 0; i < inp.length; i++){
    inp[i].addEventListener('click', concatVal, false);
}
```

Comment: Боюсь, я забыл привести html-код, и вы меня неправильно поняли.

Comment: @Mnwa, сути это [не меняет][1]. Для того, чтоб переписать код - не нужно особо знать ваш html.

   [1]:http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/eggq60df/3/

Comment: Спасибо, выручили!

Answer (score 0):

```
document.querySelectorAll('#but input').onclick = function() {
    document.querySelectorAll('.textbox').value += this.value;
}
```

Comment: Он не работает. =(